# How to drag & drop a floating imageviews in a view

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am developing android game application.The thing is i have to float/flush some balls in a view and i need to caught that balls and drag to a basket and then update the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to have your view as ImageView, and apply translate animation to imageview:

```
public TranslateAnimation (float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)
```

set onClickListener on ImageView, to drag-drop functionality, remove animation on click on ImageView in onClick method, and set on Touch Listener, and get Action down and action up co-ordinates, compare action up coordinates to basket's, and increment counter of basket accordingly.

Comment: hi jitendra please find the link:http://pastebin.com/pNdEYvJg and please let me know how can i implement ondraglistner for this..when am trying to get the pixels of getx & gety its displaying 0,0.

Comment: Hey jitendra able to float imageviews but need to drag and drop those imageviews to a basket thing needs to be fixed. let me know how can i do tat..thanks in advance..